# How do I use UpdatePanel Trigger with a control outside of panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an issue where I need to trigger 2 update panels to update when the user clicks a button which is OUTSIDE of both of these panels

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlDropDowns" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUseMeter" Event="Click"/>
  </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>


<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlChart" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUseMeter"  Event="Click"/>
  </Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:Button ID="btnUseMeter" runat="server" Text="View Meter Data" Enabled="True"   OnClientClick="lowerFlag();" />
```

I get the error

A control with ID 'btnUseMeter' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'pnlDropdowns'.

Is there a way round this?  Is it possible to use a hidden field?  If so what would the event be?  I could possibly set the value of a hidden field to say when I want the panels to update?

I have a considerable amount of HTML on this page so restructuring the page into a single panel is not an option, nor is moving the button to be inside either of the panels

I am using C# .NET 4.5

Cheers

Paul

Comment: You can add a trigger in the code behind and use `btnUseMeter.ClientID`.  Maybe that will work with `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='<%= btnUseMeter.ClientID %>'  Event="Click"/>`.  `UniqueID` should also work.

Comment: Not sure how to add the trigger in code behind?  Using %= btnUseMeter.ClientID gives the same error

Comment: Thanks that was a typo I have corrected